# get selected rows from a table with no columns labels

Tags: python, pandas

Having

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [-0.5, 'foo', 0],
    [ 1.5, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.5, 'foo', 2],
    [ 0.0, 'baz', 3],     
    [-0.6, '   ', 4],
    [-1.1, 'qux', 5],         
    ],columns='A B C'.split())
x = df[df['C'].isin([2,3])]
print x
```

the result looks like

```
     A    B  C
2 -1.5  foo  2
3  0.0  baz  3
```

while in case columns do not have labels

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [-0.5, 'foo', 0],
    [ 1.5, 'bar', 1],
    [-1.5, 'foo', 2],
    [ 0.0, 'baz', 3],     
    [-0.6, '   ', 4],
    [-1.1, 'qux', 5],         
    ])
x = df[df[[2]].isin([2,3])]
print x
```

the result looks like

```
    0    1   2
0 NaN  NaN NaN
1 NaN  NaN NaN
2 NaN  NaN   2
3 NaN  NaN   3
4 NaN  NaN NaN
5 NaN  NaN NaN
```

Is it possible in pandas to make row selection, while columns do not have labels?

Comment: `df[df[2].isin([2, 3])]` gives me the result you desire. You have one too many square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code -

```
x = df[df[2].isin([2,3])]
```

Example/Demo -

```
In [40]: x = df[df[2].isin([2,3])]

In [41]: x
Out[41]:
     0    1  2
2 -1.5  foo  2
3  0.0  baz  3
```

---

I believe the difference is this -

```
In [44]: type(df[[2]])
Out[44]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In [46]: type(df[2])
Out[46]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also be more explicit by using the `ix` indexer:

```
df[ df.ix[:,2].isin([2,3]) ]
#     0    1  2
#2 -1.5  foo  2
#3  0.0  baz  3
```